# How to retrieve parent node from child node in golang ast traversal?

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree, go-toolchain

Here is test file

```golang
func demo()  {
    name:=xxx()
    fmt.Println(name)
}
```

And my ast traversal code

```golang
ast.Inspect(f, func(node ast.Node) bool {
    assign, ok := node.(*ast.AssignStmt) // find -> name:=xxx()
    if !ok {
        return true
    }
    if assign == nil {
        return true
    }
    var expr = assign.Lhs[0]
    fmt.Println(expr) // find -> name
    fmt.Println(nodeString(assign,pass.Fset))
    return true
})
```

I find I have to travel ast from up to down like this. Find AssignStmt and then get AssignStmt->Lhs

But I need to find ast.Ident(name) first and then to find whether its parent is AssignStmt in some cases.

I am not sure is it possible that I can go from bottom to top.

Comment: I’ve used a getParent() using a state management tool called MobX, so this sort of feature certainly exists. Go might not have this feature but I haven’t looked into whether Go has a getParent function built in.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I think Golang sdk don't have this function after I check go-parser package. Now I use stack to trace this info. @Shah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manage a stack of ancestor nodes as the inspector is called:

```
var stack []ast.Node
ast.Inspect(f, func(n ast.Node) bool {

    // Look for the identifier.

    if n, ok := n.(*ast.Ident); ok {
        if n.Name == "name" {

            // Parent is stack[len(stack)-1]

            fmt.Println("found name")
            for _, n := range stack {
                fmt.Printf("%T\n", n)
            }
        }
    }

    // Manage the stack. Inspect calls a function like this:
    //   f(node)
    //   for each child {
    //      f(child) // and recursively for child's children
    //   }
    //   f(nil)
    if n == nil {
        // Done with node's children. Pop.
        stack = stack[:len(stack)-1]
    } else {
        // Push the current node for children.
        stack = append(stack, n)
    }

    return true
})
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ehUHe53oupD).